# Using async and threading inside Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'm still a newbie to threading and asyncio in Python.

I am having a tkinter frame that is supposed to stop on a stop-button click. While the frame is open, two async functions are supposed to run in the background, where one is the producer loop and the other is the consumer loop (connected through an async queue).

Everything is working so far, though I'm getting an error when pressing the stop-button. I believe I am not quitting the coros properly.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
import random
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import asyncio


class ControlWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, window=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.window = window

        tk.Button(window, text="Stop", command=self.stop).pack()

        self.thread = None
        self.tasks = None
        self.flag = False
        self.run()
        # self.window.mainloop()

    def schedule_check(self):
        self.window.after(811, self.check)

    def check(self):
        if self.thread.is_alive():
            self.schedule_check()

    def run(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=[self.main_runner()])
        self.thread.start()
        self.schedule_check()

    async def main_runner(self):
        queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.tasks = [asyncio.create_task(self.code(queue)), asyncio.create_task(self.handle_code(queue))]
        await asyncio.gather(*self.tasks)

    async def code(self, queue):
        while not self.flag:
            ran = random.randint(0, 5)
            queue.put_nowait(ran)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def handle_code(self, queue):
        while True:
            res = await queue.get()
            print(res)

    def stop(self):
        self.flag = True
        for task in self.tasks:
            task.cancel()
        self.thread.join()
        self.window.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    ControlWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run...` sounds like a terrible antipattern. What are you trying to do in the end?

Comment: I am trying to close the frame and end the program.

Comment: @AKX, I'm trying to do the same as the OP.  Would you be willing to create an answer showing a better implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, i.e. using an `Event` for the quit flag:

```
import random
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import asyncio


class AsyncThing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.quit_event = asyncio.Event()
        self.tasks = []

    def stop(self):
        self.quit_event.set()
        for task in self.tasks:
            task.cancel()

    async def main_runner(self):
        queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.tasks = [
            asyncio.create_task(self.code(queue)),
            asyncio.create_task(self.handle_code(queue)),
        ]
        try:
            await asyncio.gather(*self.tasks)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass

    async def code(self, queue):
        while not self.quit_event.is_set():
            ran = random.randint(0, 5)
            queue.put_nowait(ran)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def handle_code(self, queue: asyncio.Queue):
        while not self.quit_event.is_set():
            res = await queue.get()
            print(res)


class ControlWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, window=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = window
        tk.Button(window, text="Stop", command=self.stop).pack()
        self.thing = AsyncThing()
        self.thread = None
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=[self.thing.main_runner()])
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.thing.stop()
        self.thread.join()
        self.window.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    ControlWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected scenario, that the `gather` will propagate the `CancelledError` when any of the tasks that were passed to it is cancelled.

You can go ahead and catch the error by wrapping the `gather` with `try/except`. The below code works fine for me.

```
import random
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import asyncio


class ControlWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, window=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.window = window

        tk.Button(window, text="Stop", command=self.stop).pack()

        self.thread = None
        self.tasks = None
        self.flag = False
        self.run()
        # self.window.mainloop()

    def schedule_check(self):
        self.window.after(811, self.check)

    def check(self):
        if self.thread.is_alive():
            self.schedule_check()

    def run(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=[self.main_runner()])
        self.thread.start()
        self.schedule_check()

    async def main_runner(self):
        queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.tasks = [asyncio.create_task(self.code(queue)), asyncio.create_task(self.handle_code(queue))]
        
        try:
            await asyncio.gather(*self.tasks)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("Gather was cancelled and you can cleanup the things here")

    async def code(self, queue):
        while not self.flag:
            ran = random.randint(0, 5)
            queue.put_nowait(ran)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            

    async def handle_code(self, queue):
        while True:
            res = await queue.get()
            print(res)

    def stop(self):
        self.flag = True
        for task in self.tasks:
            task.cancel()

        self.thread.join()
        self.window.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    ControlWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

But, try to understand the implications of the same by going through the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63356323).